# How to realize memory locality of object array in Java?

Tags: java

I meet a following problem in Java:

For example

I have a wrapped `class Node`

```
class Node{
    int param_1, param_2,...; 
}
```

I will frequently access nearby locations of some Node array, e.g. `Node[] array`, like:

```
Node[] array = new Node[10];
```

I need to frequently read `array[i].param_k` and `array[i+1].param_j`. In `Node[] array`, we just localize the references of objects of this wrapped class `Node`, that is `node_i` and `node_i+1`'s references are stored nearby in `array`. However the heap location of `node_i` and `node_i+1` are far apart. After I manipulated the `node_i`'s member variable, I will miss cache when I read `node_i+1`'s member variable.

My question:

Is there any **equivalent realization** of **same functionality** of `wrapped class array` which can make physical memory localized?

Comment: There's no (legal) way of working with direct memory in Java. And you should not try to do it, since location of an object can be changed by the GC without notice. Why can't you use a simple array? You can access any `Node` by its index and find neighbor nodes using that index as well.

Comment: @PavelSmirnov `node_i` and `node_i+1`'s references are stored nearby in `array`. However the heap location of `node_i` and `node_i+1` are far apart. After I manipulated the `node_i`'s member variable, I will miss cache when I read `node_i+1`'s member variable.

Comment: Obviously some mass data, to care about such things. `int[][]`, or at least `int[] params`.

Comment: @maplemaple, so you're worried about cache misses? Then you have probably chosen the wrong language. Java abstarcts from those kinds of things, relieving a developer of such low-level optimization and tricks (most of them are done underhood). However, there's a test project Valhalla, which has introduced so called value types, which do similar to what you want. Anyway, as for now, this sounds like a premature optimization. Are you sure you have significant performance problems caused by cache misses that you need to dive into that low-level optimizations?